# Bonobo 6.5.0 does not startup

Tags: bonobo

I cannot get the Bonobo Git Server to work. I think the problem may be that there is no web page to load (example index.htm, etc.).
The following snapshot is what is displayed when I request http://localhost/Bonobo.Git.Server/

[Snapshot of Bonobo.Git.Server directory listings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsJdt.png)
[Snapshot of Web Server (IIS) display.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVIdz.png)

Comment: Have you changed App_Data permissions?

Comment: Yes, I had. Just this morning I downloaded a new copy and again followed the installation instructions on the Bonobo site. Still the same issue. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it had nothing to do with the instructions on the Bonobo site.
The instructions specified in the readme.md were my first clue.

- Don't forget to register .NET framework with your IIS
- Run `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir` with administrator privileges

That was tried but the app informed my that I would have to uninstall what I already had installed, ASP.NET 4.8, to install a previous ASP.NET 4.5 version.

So, I enabled ASP.NET 3.5 as well as a few more features to the IIS capability just incase I might need them.

Now it works!

The following was helpful:
https://www.google.com/search?q=add+NET+4.5+to+IIS&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS915US915&oq=add+NET+4.5+to+IIS&aqs=chrome..69i57.12325j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8